# Datarow's items not being treated as Integer in Extension Method, but exception implies it is being treated as an Integer

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I implemented an extension method on Integer (this is a simplified example that also shows the error)

```
<Extension()>
Public Function IsPositive(ByVal item As Integer) As Boolean
    Return item > 0
End Function
```

I then try to call the extension method on a datarow's item:

```
Dim dtMyTable As DataTable
dtMyTable = GetInfoFromDatabase()
If dtMyTable.Rows(0).Item("nCount").IsPositive() Then
```

This gives me the exception:

```
Public member 'IsPostive' on type 'Integer' not found.
```

I assume this is because dtMyTable.Rows(0).Item("nCount") is actually an object, not an integer. The exception seems to understand that that isn't the case, so I'm not sure why that's different, but it is.

However, if I try to call the same method as if it's just  a regular method, it works without complaint

```
If IsPositive(dtMyTable.Rows(0).Item("nCount")) Then
```

I would rather call it the former way. I know it's possible to just save the value to a variable and then call the extension on that variable, but that seems like a needless extra step.

Is there any way to get the former method to work without adding an extra variable assignment every time I need to call it, or changing the extension method to work on Objects?

Comment: since the row is not the incoming type of the first parameter, you will probably need to cast it. `If CInt(dtMyTable.Rows(0).Item("nCount")).IsPositive() Then`

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the exception isn't implying it's an integer, I think its saying you're trying to use IsPositive and it doesn't find an Integer to use it on.

Comment: @Charles May : If I try to use IsPositive on a boolean in my datarow, I get "Public member 'IsPositive' on type 'Boolean' not found." instead.

Comment: The inline casting is an okay solution, but it would be nice not to have to do that. If that ends up being required, though, I can live with that. You should make that a full answer.

Comment: I think a DataColumn in a DataTable can have a DataType set. Has this been set for this column?

Comment: @Mary : It's a {Name = "Int32" FullName = "System.Int32"} according to the DataType. I tried changing the type on item in IsPositive() to Int32, but still get the exact same exception (I assume because Integer and Int32 are the same thing).

Comment: Extension Methods are resolved when the code is compiled into simple method calls.  You are experiencing a run-time late binding error in which the late-binding implemented  by VB can not find the member `IsPositive`  on the object of the binding (in this case an integer).  If you had `Option Strict` enabled, your code would not even compile.

Comment: @TnTinMn : My understanding was that the first method of calling IsPositive() would be converted into something exactly the same as the second method of calling IsPositive(), and that would be done at compile time. It sounds like, instead, it tries to do that at runtime, and fails? I guess I just don't understand the subtle difference between the two, then.

Comment: You have passed over the main thrust of my comment, **Late-Binding**.  The `DataRow.Item` property is type `Object`.  When Option Strict is Off, VB allows you to use the dot notation for referencing properties or methods on variables typed as Object.  However, these are not looked for (resolved) until the code tries to execute (hence it is late bound vs early bound).  Not the best write-up, but see: [Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/) for more info.

Comment: Okay, I think I see. During early binding/compile time, the type of the return from .Item() is Object, which doesn't match the signature for IsPositive(), so it can't convert option 1 to option 2 at that point. And during late binding/run time, it doesn't have access to IsPositive() to know that it needs to call that, despite it having the correct signature for it. So, then, Charles May's answer is the only solution if I want to keep this an extension method, there's no hack I can do to make it work. Thanks, TnTinMn, that explains a lot.